# Can optuna trials be purged / deleted? (dealing with regime changes over time)

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters, optuna

**Context:** The ML problem I'm modelling changes over time with different regimes - such that the model weights and best model hyper params change over time.

**Issue:** For a given `optuna.study`, when I call `study.best_trial.params`, this might identify the best trial as one that is far in the past - which represents an outdated point of view on the best params for the current regime.

**Secondary issue:** when optuna samples hyperparams to evaluate during optimization, it uses results from all trials to inform where to sample from probabilistically. As the regime changes, older trials are less relevant to consider in this process.

**Question:** Is there a way to purge or delete or ignore older trials as time passes by? Such that the above two issues are resolved?

**Reflection:**

- Perhaps I'm mistaken RE how optuna works. I assume the best way to get best_params is to call `optuna.study.best_trial.params` which looks over all historical trials and greedly find the one with the best optimisation score and returns the params used for that run.
- But perhaps there is a different way to get the best_params over the past N trials?
- Or perhaps I should just focus on getting the best params from the LAST trial - which would be a good representation of the current regime. I can use `study.get_trials()[-1].params` to get this I believe.

Thanks for any feedback / advice.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution below - in case helpful for others. This purges older trials from a study and maintains `num_trials_to_keep` trials in the study.

```
                    num_trials = study.trials[-1].number
                    num_trials_to_keep = 50

                    trials_to_keep = [
                        optuna.trial.create_trial(
                            state=TrialState.COMPLETE,
                            params=t.params,
                            user_attrs=t.user_attrs,
                            system_attrs=t.system_attrs,
                            intermediate_values=t.intermediate_values,
                            distributions=t.distributions,
                            value=t.value
                        ) for t in study.trials if t.number > num_trials - num_trials_to_keep]

                    # Delete study before recreating
                    optuna.delete_study(study_name=ho_study_name, storage=ho_storage_name)

                    # Recreate study and add trials to keep
                    new_study = optuna.create_study(
                        pruner=optuna.pruners.MedianPruner(n_warmup_steps=5),
                        direction="maximize",
                        study_name=ho_study_name,
                        storage=ho_storage_name,
                        load_if_exists=True)
                    new_study.add_trials(trials_to_keep)
```